# Cooling Peltier Maths

Tags: temperature, heat, math, peltier, cooling

I want to construct a peltier cooling system. However, I have limited mathematical skills. Can I ask how to do the maths to calculate how much temperature differential can a specific peltier cool taking heatsinks, fan air flow, volume of liquid, container, etc, into account.Thank you so much.

Comment: There is no simpler method than the datasheet.  Which part is not clear?  You need efficient cooling of hot side with high velocity air over heatsink and maximum thermal conductance on cool side with best insulation of cool side possible.

Comment: By insulation, is it appropriate to incorporate another heat on the cold side? I am trying to cool a water block.

Comment: No . It is important not to waste cooling power by insulating the water block by some Rth (‘C/W) and use thin silver oxide thermal paste for low Rth with ideal coplanarity and surface roughness  or as good as you can manage) and use a CPU heatsink and fan to reduce hotside as much as possible, or heat up water to keep cool with sufficient flow.

Comment: ideally the Pelletier device has the lowest temperature offset between hot and cold side when you add Electrical,power and transfer all the thermal energy efficiently. Hot side to cooler and cool side to block.

Comment: my bad. I meant HEATSINK on the cold side

Comment: Yes your cooler block is the heatsink but it must the container must be insulated.